# svgr Unknown command line option: '--ext' in azure devops pipeline

Tags: svg, npm, azure-devops

Developing locally on a Mac, I have this as an npm script in package json:

`npx @svgr/cli --template path/to/template.js --ext .tsx my-icon.svg`

This works as expected.

However, the Azure DevOps pipeline build fails when this script is run with the message `Unknown command line option: '--ext'`

It's not running in a container, so I assume it's running in a windows environment and that has something to do with this error.

`--ext tsx` is a valid command line argument; like i said it works in a unix environment (*macbook pro)

Any idea how to get around it?

So far I've tried the extension to the config file, but that particular option is only available through the cli.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: Can you also share the build logs with debug enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with GitHub actions, and my solution was to use

```
./node_modules/.bin/svgr --template path/to/template.js --ext .tsx my-icon.svg
```

Not sure if it will work in your case, though.